# How to validate that user token is valid before reset password in Asp.Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net core MVC for my application and I implemented the reset password functionality and it is working fine. Let me show how it is implemented. When a user requests to reset the password, the application creates a token as below:

```
var token = _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user);
```

The application sends an email to the user and when the user hit the link, it comes on the page where the user reset the password. I am resetting as below:

```
ChangePasswordAsync(user, token, password);
```

It is working fine. But I want to validate the token is valid or not before changing password. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

`UserManager` has a public method, `VerifyUserTokenAsync`, which is likely what you're after. If you check the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/394eb3ca13c662e1c2288372e05f46fbcb149c16/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1705), you'll see how this is used inside of `ResetPasswordAsync`:

```
VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, Options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider, ResetPasswordTokenPurpose, token)
```

So, it relies on a magic string, but you should be able to use the same value to get a true or false value, something like:

```
if(await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, _userManager.Options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider, "ResetPassword", token))
{
    await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);
}
else
{
    // handle a bad token however you see fit...
}
```

This untested, so I can't promise it works as-is.

Comment: This helped me and it was what I was looking for. However, I get False every time, even when copy pasting the token.

Comment: Ah, ok, I figured it out. 
When creating ConfirmMail Token, it's necessary to Encode it, however, when creating PasswordReset token, you should NOT encode it. 
Kinda funny, but oh well

Answer (score 2):

Token will be validated by the Identity Framework. So I guess you don't need to do that manually.

```
var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
```

Result will have a descriptive message if it fails.

Cheers,

Comment: I know. I am already doing it. But i want to validate it manually because i want if the token is invalid the don't show the reset page and redirect to 404.

Comment: It doesn't work that way by design. If you can get a reliable failure response, then you can brute force a valid token, simply by generating random tokens and throwing them at your server until a 404 is no longer returned. By returning the password reset in all cases, it make it far more challenging.